# show that for every $a \in D$ is a function $K_a \in H ^ 2 (D)$ such that $f (a)=\langle f, K_a \rangle_{H^2(D)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the Hardy space $H ^ 2 (D)$, where D is an open set in the complex. Show that$ H ^ 2 (D)$ is a Hilbert space, and show that for every $a \in D$ is a function $K_a \in H ^ 2 (D)$ such that $$f (a)=\langle f, K_a \rangle_{H^2(D)}.$$

Comment: Do you know Riesz' representation theorem?

Comment: Yes,i know yes.

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Have you shown that $H^2$ is a Hardy space? If so, show that $f \mapsto f(a)$ is a continuous functional on $H^2$ and by Riesz you are done.